# Shanghai Stock Exchange data API

Tags: finance, china, stock

A friend asked me to develop a data product around Shanghai Stock Exchange data for him.

I don't think either of us realized that

- Google Finance's API is defunct
- Several others only have 1 stock representing a composite of that entire market
- Quandl charges a minimal price of $360 for their version of the data

Is there anywhere that would at least let me have *some* of the data to play with, before making a major investment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you actually can get this data from Yahoo! Finance, but you just need to know the numeric representation of the Chinese ticker symbols of interest.

> ```
>  prices
> # A tibble: 141,040 x 8
>    symbol    date        open  high   low close   volume adjusted
>    <chr>     <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
>  1 600000.ss 2018-09-03 10.3   10.3 10.2   10.2 14309539     10.2
>  2 600000.ss 2018-09-04 10.2   10.4 10.2   10.4 16353060     10.4
>  3 600000.ss 2018-09-05 10.3   10.4 10.1   10.1 22729232     10.1
>  4 600000.ss 2018-09-06 10.1   10.2 10.1   10.1 10546916     10.1
>  5 600000.ss 2018-09-07 10.2   10.2 10.1   10.2  8995716     10.2
>  6 600000.ss 2018-09-10 10.2   10.2 10.1   10.2 11822813     10.2
>  7 600000.ss 2018-09-11 10.2   10.3  9.98  10.0 19689042     10.0
>  8 600000.ss 2018-09-12  9.99  10.1  9.95  10.0 16506103     10.0
>  9 600000.ss 2018-09-13 10.2   10.3 10.1   10.3 29417198     10.3
> 10 600000.ss 2018-09-14 10.4   10.4 10.2   10.3 16450780     10.3
> ```

It also requires you to know the exchange in China as that info is not provided (so, for instance, you have to know that the Shanghai stock codes begin with a 6, so if you see one with a 0 or a 2 in the first character that's actually the Shenzhen exchange not Shanghai). In the example above I appended ".ss" to reflect that.